# Perl accessing and printing data from a html folder in a parent folder

Tags: html, perl, file

so I have a Folder called DATA, and it includes the following: part1.html, part2.html, part3.html, HTML.htm,  plain.html, and jojo.jsp.

Now i use the following commmand to open the DATA folder and extract the files containing .htm

```
opendir(DIR,'DATA');
my(@dir) = grep /\.htm/, readdir (DIR);
closedir(DIR);
```

It successfully prints out the name of the files containing the extensions .html . Now i wish to use the html file that are filtered and print the data out into the cygwin terminal. I tried to use the files and stored it to a variable, and use a foreach loop to open the first html file using Filehandler and printing out the data init. The loop will repeat itself and do the same for all the other html files. But i seemed to run into the error! Please help!

```
my $value = join(@dir); 
print "$value\n";

foreach(@dir){
my $movies =  my $value;
open (FHD,  $movies) || die " could not open $movies\n";
my @movies = <FHD>;

my $value2 = join(', ', @movies); 
print "$value2\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

What's with this line?

```
my $movies =  my $value;
```

You're making this a lot harder than it needs to be.

Just use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to read the directory as that will automatically include the path information on your found files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

for my $html (glob('DATA/*.htm*')) {
    print "File: $html\n";

    open my $fh, '<', $html;
    print <$fh>;
}
```